# tf.browser.fromPixels() not working because "DOM is not ready yet"

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, dom-events, tensorflow.js, domcontentloaded

I'm trying to play with TensorFlow.js's `tf.browser.fromPixels()` function. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
backend_webgl.ts:309 Uncaught Error: The DOM is not ready yet. Please call tf.browser.fromPixels() once the DOM is ready. One way to do that is to add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` on the document object
    at e.fromPixels (backend_webgl.ts:309)
    at t.fromPixels (engine.ts:870)
    at fromPixels_ (browser.ts:55)
    at Object.fromPixels (operation.ts:45)
    at ex4.html:10
```

But I'm calling `tf.browser.fromPixels()` from inside a function passed to `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`. Any idea why I'm getting this error and how to get the `fromPixels` function to work?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.7/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="test" src="https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg">
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ev => {
            const img = document.getElementById('test')
            tf.browser.fromPixels(img).print()
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
          throw new Error(
              'The DOM is not ready yet. Please call ' +
              'tf.browser.fromPixels() once the DOM is ready. One way to ' +
              'do that is to add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` ' +
              'on the document object');
        }
```

[Github tensorflow/tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/aa92053a8d7c640fe9e685e254655f417480cf0d/tfjs-core/src/backends/webgl/backend_webgl.ts#L313-L321)

According to the code above, the error is thrown because `document.readyState` isn't `complete`.

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event
>
> The readyState of a document can be one of following:
>
> loading
>   The document is still loading.
>
> interactive
>   The document has finished loading and the document has been parsed but sub-resources such as images, stylesheets and frames are still loading.
>
> complete
>   The document and all sub-resources have finished loading. The state indicates that the load event is about to fire.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

`DOMContentLoaded` is called before any sub-resources aren't loaded yet.So At the time of your code is executed, `document.readyState` is still `interactive`.

Just ignore what the error says and try `load` event listener instead.

Comment: @at. FYI, I made a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/pull/1852) fixing the error message and It was merged. It'll be fixed in the next version.